# Add all the rows in a column and display it at the end of the file

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to add all the rows in the column and display the output in a single row. Here is my source code:

```
csvio = StringIO()
header = ['Name','Unit1','Unit2','Marks']
writer = csv.writer(csvio)
writer.writerow(header)

for ut in uts:
    data = marks_helper()
    tot = 0
    row = []

    if data['a'] > 0.01 or data['b'] > .01 or data['a'] > .01:
        row.append(ut.name)
        row.append(round(data['a'],1))
        row.append(round(data['abd'], 1))
        tot = Decimal(data['abd']) - Decimal(data['a'])
        row.append("{}".format('%.2f' % tot))                      

    if len(row) >= 1:
        writer.writerow(row)               

local = open( 'filename' , 'w')
local.write(csvio.getvalue())
local.close()  

csvio.seek(0)
breakdown = csvio.getvalue()
```

I am trying to get the sum of all the rows in Marks column and display that in a new row. I have tried this:

```
for x in tot:
    x += int(row[3])
    row.append(x)
```

but I get this error:

```
'Decimal' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line makes *tot* a Decimal object:

```
tot = Decimal(data['abd']) - Decimal(data['a'])
```

That means that its a number, like an int or a float, so not iterable.

```
# This code, with tot being a Decimal ...
for x in tot:
    pass

# ... is the equivalent of this
for x in 1:
    pass

# ... or this
for x in 0.1:
    pass
```

What you want is probably:

```
# Before looping over uts
marks_total = Decimal()

for ut in uts:
    # ... after calculating tot
    marks_total += tot  # Accumulate total of all tot

# After loop
writer.writerow(['', '', '', marks_total])
```

If you want to iterate over a list you can do this, but it's slower and pointless:

```
# Before loop
all_tots = []

for ut in uts:
    # ... after calculating tot
    all_tots.append(tot)

# After loop
writer.writerow(['', '', '', sum(all_tots)])
```

Comment: Maybe you're not putting the code in the correct order? marks_total should at the end be the accumulated sum of all tot. Do not write that using writer.writerow() until the program has exited the "for ut in uts" loop.

Comment: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/addition_assignment.html

Comment: Then you do marks_total = [] before loop, marks_total.append(tot) in loop and writer.writerow(['', '', '', sum(marks_total)]) after loop. Same result as what I suggested, but uses more memory and is slower.